# How to addEventListener with React Hooks when the function needs to read state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I use React with function components and hooks - and I am trying to add a scroll listener which modified the state basing on the current value of the state.

My current code looks like this:

```
const [isAboveTheFoldVisible, setAboveTheFoldVisible] = useState(true);

const scrollHandler = useCallback(
    () => {         
        if (window.pageYOffset >= window.innerHeight) {
            if (isAboveTheFoldVisible) {
                setAboveTheFoldVisible(false);
            }
        } else if (!isAboveTheFoldVisible) {
            setAboveTheFoldVisible(true);
        }
    },
    [isAboveTheFoldVisible]
);

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
    return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
    };
}, [scrollHandler]);
```

However, because of the [scrollHandler] in useEffect, the listeners are removed and re-added when isAboveTheFoldVisible is being set... which is not necessary.

Possible solutions that I see:

1. Have two `useEffect`s, one with adding scroll listener and setting a state like scroll position without reading anything
   `const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0)`
   and then second having the `scrollPosition` as a `[scrollPosition]`. 
   I do not really like this solution because it's not really explicit why we're setting the `scrollPosition` when you see the listener.
2. Using custom hook like useEventListener https://usehooks.com/useEventListener/
3. Using ref to reference the handler.
4. Do not read the value of `isAboveTheFoldVisible` and set the new state anyway. React compares the old state with the new one and if it's same it won't re-render.